# Does $\diamondsuit(\kappa)$ provably hold at Woodins or inaccessible Jónssons $\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, infinite-combinatorics

Usually the question whether the [diamond principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_principle) $\diamondsuit(\kappa)$ holds for some large cardinal $\kappa$ only concerns large cardinal notions of very low consistency (among the weakly compacts). Partly since it *does* hold for all [subtle cardinals](http://cantorsattic.info/Ineffable#Subtle_cardinal), which are only barely stronger than the weakly compacts, and pretty much every large cardinal notion below a weakly compact has been shown to consistently *not* satisfy it (see [Failure of diamond at large cardinals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137036/failure-of-diamond-at-large-cardinals) and [Ben Neria ('17)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01611)).

That subtle cardinals satisfy diamond of course means that almost all large cardinals *do* satisfy it as well, but there are some strange ones lying around though, including [Woodin cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodin_cardinal) and inaccessible [Jónsson cardinals](http://cantorsattic.info/Jonsson). Is anything known about diamond holding for any of these two?

Comment: The issue is not with diamond holding but rather with its failure.

Comment: But that's basically the same question, no?

Comment: Diamond hold at them in known core models. The question of whether diamond can fail at a weakly compact cardinal is a major open question.

Comment: See [Failure of diamond at large cardinals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137036/failure-of-diamond-at-large-cardinals)

Comment: Yes, but since Woodins aren't weakly compact in general and whether Jonssons are is still open, the 'weakly compact diamond programme' probably wouldn't be able to give an answer to my question. My question is perhaps then if diamond *provably* holds for Woodins and inaccessible Jonssons. I'll change the title.

Answer (score 13):

This is a partial answer. I will show that if $\delta$ is Woodin then $\diamondsuit_\delta$ holds.

**Claim:** Any Woodin cardinal is subtle.

**Proof:** Let $\delta$ be a Woodin cardinal. Let $\vec{A} = \langle A_\alpha \mid \alpha < \delta\rangle$ be a sequence a sets, $A_\alpha \subseteq \alpha$ and let $C$ be a club in $\delta$. We want to find $\alpha < \beta$ in $C$ such that $A_\alpha = A_\beta \cap \alpha$.

Since $\delta$ is Woodin, there is a cardinal $\kappa < \delta$ which is $\vec{A} \times C$-strong up to $\delta$. Thus, $\kappa \in C$ and there is an elementary emebedding $j\colon V\to M$, such that :

- $\mathrm{crit}\ j = \kappa$,
- $j(\vec{A}) \restriction \kappa + 1 = \vec{A} \restriction \kappa + 1$,

In $M$, $j(\vec{A})(j(\kappa)) \cap \kappa = j(\vec{A})(\kappa) = A_\kappa$ and $\kappa, j(\kappa) \in j(C)$. By elementarity, there is $\alpha < \kappa$ in $C$ such that $A_\alpha = A_\kappa \cap \alpha$.

Comment: It's a subtle claim...

Comment: Ah, wonderful! Thanks Yair. One question: do you mean that $\kappa,j(\kappa)\in j(C)$, where $\kappa\in j(C)$ since $j$ is $C$-strong? I at least can't see why $j(\kappa)$ should be in $C$.

Comment: Yes. It was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by "inaccessible Jónsson" you meant a regular limit cardinal of uncountable cofinality which is Jónsson; then using the arguments of [1] (Theorem 15 p.115), we have

> if $\mathbb{P}$ is c.c.c. and $\kappa$ is Jónsson then for any $V$-generic $G\subset \mathbb{P}$, $V[G]\vDash$ "$\kappa$ is Jónsson".

In particular, if $\kappa$ is Jónsson, and $G\subset \mathbb{P}=\mathsf{Fn}(\kappa^{+}, 2)$ is $V$-generic, then

> $V[G] \vDash $ "$\kappa < 2^{\aleph_0}$ and $\kappa$ is Jónsson."

hence $V[G] \vDash \neg \diamondsuit_\kappa$ and $\kappa$ is Jónsson. Moreover, If we started with $\kappa$ which was a regular limit cardinal then the same holds for $\kappa$ in $V[G]$.

[1] *Devlin, Keith J.*, [**Some weak versions of large cardinal axioms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(73)90010-7), Ann. Math. Logic 5, 291-325 (1973). [ZBL0279.02051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0279.02051).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm afraid that by 'inaccessible' I mean 'strongly inaccessible' though.

Comment: @DanSaattrupNielsen I thought it seemed to easy.. thanks.